# Using Word Web Add-In and Javascript and trying to inserttext based on Cursor position and not the end or start of document

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I'm doing a body.insertText("insert my text here", Word.InsertLocation.end) and it always put at the END of the document where I would like it.  BUT, what I really want is the ability to inserttext where the CURSOR actually is.  Is this possible? There is InsertLocation.start which doesn't work, and InsertLocation.before, which doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using the "getSelection" method to get the current selection range, then insert the text in the range

Comment: You need to say more than "doesn't work". What do you expect to see and what do you actually see?

Comment: I need it to insert were the CURSOR is located.  It ALWAYS appends to the end of the document even though the cursor is at the top of the document